# Prevent $ From Being Interpreted as the Start of a Variable at the Command Line in a PHP Script

Tags: php, exec

I have some text piped into a php script at the command line.

```
exec('echo ' . escapeshellarg($text) . ' | script.php');
```

Sometimes $text has a dollar sign in it, like `The ticket cost $1 and was easy to get.`

If I save a copy of the output from escapeshellarg($text) it shows correctly.

Inside script.php I get the variable with `$text = $this->getStdin(Maintenance::STDIN_ALL);` however, if I save a copy of the $text at this point it has replaced $1 with line breaks, something like:

```
The ticket cost 

 and was easy to get.
```

How can I prevent the text from being modified?

Comment: what is `$this->getStdin()`?

Comment: And how are you saving the value of `$text`?

Comment: `exec()` isn't doing anything wrong. If you redirect the output to a file instead of piping to `script.php`, you'll see the literal `$`.